# How to save drop-down text in form data

Tags: kentico

I have a drop-down field in my custom form. By default, the selected value is getting saved in the form data, though I want the value text to be saved. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: How is the drop-down filled? Can't you just set the Display value to also be the Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration of that field you need to specify the value to be the text as well. E.g.:

```
text 1;text 1
text 2;text 2
```

Or if it is configured as an SQL query, you can select same column twice:

```
SELECT Column, Column FROM Table
```

Comment: I need ID to be saved in place of value since I need ID's for some other purpose.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. This two values are up to you, so you can have any pair you need. If you need to store ID, return the ID if you need a text, return a text.